# Git issues when converting from single-programmer project using git in Xcode to a project where there are multiple engineers

Tags: xcode, git

I'm inheriting an Xcode project from an engineer who built this project over 2 years, using git in Xcode but never committing or pushing to a repo like Github.

When I `cd` into the project, I get: `fatal: unable to read 45d2edd52b4abd09ab4d5f78e9eaf4183235f555`

Running `vi .git/HEAD` gives me: `ref: refs/heads/followers`, which is the branch the project is on when I `cd` into it for the first time after downloading.

If I do check out `master`, from `followers` this happens:

```
-> gco master
fatal: reference is not a tree: master
```

`git status` and `git log` give me `fatal: bad object HEAD`

When I run `git fetch`, I get:

```
error: refs/remotes/origin/master does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/remotes/origin/profileTab does not point to a valid object!
remote: Counting objects: 759, done.
remote: Total 759 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 759
Receiving objects: 100% (759/759), 2.50 MiB | 7.66 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (333/333), done.
error: refs/heads/1144 does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/heads/Boost does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/heads/CMO does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/heads/RemoveSVPullToRefresh does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/heads/accessorycategory does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/heads/backup does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/heads/chimpIntegration does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/heads/compulsaryCheckout does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/heads/depopIntegration does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/heads/dev does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/heads/explorewithlatestfirst does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/heads/followers does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/heads/incrementBadge does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/heads/listforothers does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/heads/master does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/heads/messaging does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/heads/newCreateVCFlow does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/heads/newimagepicker does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/heads/postingBanner does not point to a valid object!
fatal: bad object HEAD
error: ssh://github.com/{user who isn't me}/wtbtest.git did not send all necessary objects
```

The `followers` branch is a clean `master`, essentially, but I want to set this project up for multiple developers to work on it and act and behave like a normal project that uses git.

Would love any tips on how to resolve this. Thanks!

Comment: It seems some of the meta data are broken. If the history is not important, you could make the current code as the first commit, so that all the team members can make further development on this base.

Comment: In a test branch I removed the .git file, then did a new `git init` and committed everything as a "new first commit." so that's one option for sure